# How to process users in one specific order using map o each function?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, promise, parse-cloud-code

I create a cloud function that process all the items in a specific order and then make a network request to an API for each item and update them with the result of the API.

I tried to do something like this. But the order is not respected and the computation of the "remainingCredits" is wrong. 
Note that the function "getUserPageView()" make an API call and return a promise with the result.

```
  query.descending("createdAt");
  return query.find().then(function(items) {
        var remainingCredits=0;
        var promises= _.map(items, function(item){
            var credit=item.get("credit_buy");
            return getUserPageView(123, new Date()).then(function(pageviews){
                var usedCredit=credit-pageviews;
                if(remainingCredits>0)
                    return remainingCredits+credit;
                if(credit-usedCredit<=0){
                    console.log("usedCredit:"+usedCredit);
                    item.set("used",true);
                    return 0;
                }else{
                    remainingCredits+=usedCredit;
                    return remainingCredits;
                }
            });
        });
        return Parse.Promise.when(promises);
    }).then(function(results){
        console.log(_.toArray(arguments));
        status.success();
    }, function(error){
        status.error(error);
    });
```

How can I calculate the remainingCredits with a specific order?

Comment: Make a JSFiddle of this, preferably with some example data

Comment: I will do this in another way to simplify the task. Anyway it remains the dubt to how to serialize with a specific order asyncronous call of function. For example when I have to do a calculation in a specific order of data.

Comment: When asynchronous operations are involved and you want a specific order, you cannot use looping constructs like `_.map()` because these will launch all requests in parallel so you lose control of the order that you process the results.  Instead, you have to either collect all the results and then process them in order when they are all done or serialize the requests where you launch one request, wait for it to finish, process it, then launch the next one, etc...  Either the Async library or promises can help you do this.

Comment: When the process gets to `console.log(_.toArray(arguments))`, the array logged will be in the original order of the `items` that were earlier mapped to promises. Order is preserved.

Comment: However, you shouldn't be processing the asynchronously derived data as it arrives. By waiting for all the data, then processing it, you should get the results you expect.

Answer (score 0):

If it is important to process the asynchronously derived data in the original `items` order, then it should not be processed as it arrives.

Try waiting for all the data to arrive, then process it.

```
query.descending("createdAt");
return query.find().then(function(items) {
    return Parse.Promise.when(_.map(items, function(item) {
        return getUserPageView(123, new Date()).then(function(pageviews) {
            //here, create an object with all the data required for later processing
            return {
                item: item,
                pageviews: pageviews
            };
        });
    }));
}).then(function() {
    var remainingCredits = 0;
    var runningBalance _.toArray(arguments).map(function(obj) {
        var credit = obj.item.get("credit_buy");
        var usedCredit = credit - obj.pageviews;
        if(remainingCredits > 0)
            return remainingCredits + credit;
        if((credit - usedCredit) <= 0) {
            console.log("usedCredit:" + usedCredit);
            obj.item.set("used", true);
            return 0;
        } else {
            remainingCredits += usedCredit;
            return remainingCredits;
        }
    });
    console.log(runningBalance);
    status.success();
    return runningBalance;
}, function(error) {
    status.error(error);
});
```

I invented the variable name `runningBalance` because that is what you appear to be trying to create.

I tried to verify the processing of credits and can only suggest that it needs looking at again. For example, if `usedCredit = credit - obj.pageviews`, then the test `if((credit - usedCredit) <= 0) {...}` will simplify to `if(obj.pageviews <= 0) {...}`, which doesn't seem right.